# Characterise all pairs of n/m stars that have the same inner radius

Tags: discrete-geometry, gm.general-mathematics

### Geometry, algebra, and examples

Let *n* and *m* be integers, with 2 ≤ *m* < *n*/2. Consider the bounding polygon of an *n*/*m* star (that is, a star with *n* points each of which connects to the two points ±*m* away) inscribed in the unit circle. Such a bounding polygon has 2*n* points, *n* on the unit circle and *n* on an inner circle with:

$Inner Radius = \frac{\cos{\left(\frac{\pi m}{n}\right)}}{\cos{\left(\frac{\pi (m-1)}{n}\right)}}$

[image: 5/2 star]

[image: 8/2 star]

[image: 8/3 star]

E.g., inner radius of 5/2 star is ½(3–√5) ≈ 0.381966, that of 8/2 star is √(2–√2) ≈ 0.765367, and that of 8/3 star is √(1–√½) ≈ 0.541196.

I wish to characterise the different stars that have the same inner radius. Two series of pairs are known: ∀ integer *i* ≥ 2, stars (6*i*–2)/*i* and (18*i*–6)/(6*i*–2) have the same inner radius, as do (6*i*–4)/*i* and (18*i*–12)/(6*i*–3). Proof that these pairs do match is boringly elementary, given the identity Cos[θ] Cos[φ] = ½Cos[θ+φ] + ½Cos[θ–φ], and at [jdawiseman.com](http://www.jdawiseman.com/papers/easymath/open_questions.html#stars).

But are there any other non-trivial matches, perhaps another series, perhaps sporadic?

(I know that any other matches must have inner radius > 0.998122, and of course strictly < 1. So any other matches shown as a graphic smaller than about 2k pixels across must look like a circle — practical rather than proper progress.)

### The Question

> Characterise all pairs of stars, *n*₁/*m*₁ and *n*₂/*m*₂ (all integer), such that the stars have the same inner radius. It is known that there are two series of such pairs of stars, {(6*i*–2)/*i*, (18*i*–6)/(6*i*–2)} and {(6*i*–4)/*i*, (18*i*–12)/(6*i*–3)}. Are there any other series? Are there any sporadic matches?

Comment: In short, you are asking the following question. If $m_1,m_2,n_1,n_2$ are integers with $2\leq m_1<n_1/2$ and $2\leq m_2<n_2/2$ and $n_1\leq n_2$, and if $f(n_1,m_1)=f(n_2,m_2)$, with $f(n,m):=\cos(\pi*m/n)/\cos(\pi*(m-1)/n)$, then is it the case that either $n_2=n_1$ or $n_2=6n_1-2$ or $n_2=6n_1-3$?

Comment: Did you mean to write that “either $n_2=n_1$ or $n_2=3n_1$”?

Even so, I think that is necessary, but not sufficient. Might there be multiple $m$s for any particular $n_1$ and $n_2$?

Comment: Yes I've got my $m$s and $n$s mixed up. The only reason I wrote that comment was that even though your motivation is clearly the pretty stars, for me the pretty stars were a red herring and the maths question was brief and easy to formulate (even though I failed to get it right ;-) ). If I'd been posting your question I would have had (the correct version of) my comment right at the beginning, and then all the other stuff underneath as motivation. This doesn't change the fact that I can't do the question, by the way. I checked on a computer that for $n_1,n_2<=25$ or so there were no other ex's

Comment: In so far as the problem has any elegance and pleasure, it comes from the geometric motivation. The algebra — for my taste — is merely a tiresome necessity.

Comment: This is a special case of a problem that was solved by Gerrit Bol in 1936;
that nearly-forgotten result was rediscovered, using slightly different
methods, by Bjorn Poonen and Michael Rubinstein: see their paper
"The Number of Intersection Points Made by the Diagonals of a Regular Polygon",
*SIAM J. Discrete Math* **11** (1998), 135-156 
(http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/ngon.pdf).


Comment: Ooops: offered bounty without noticing comment that is an answer. Noam: please grab prize by posting as a answer.

Comment: Except that I think that it isn’t an answer. That paper is about how many diagonals of a n-gon meet at a single non-central point. But this question has two n-gons, with differing n’s. 

Comment: If the inner radii coincide then we can rotate the two stars until
they share an inner vertex.  The outer vertices are then contained
among the vertices of a single regular $N$-gon where $N$ is at most
something like the product of the two different $n$'s.  Now apply
Bol / Poonen-Rubinstein.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Expanding some on my comment of a few days ago]

This is a special case of a problem that was solved by Gerrit Bol in 1936 [B];
that nearly-forgotten result was rediscovered, using slightly different
methods, by Bjorn Poonen and Michael Rubinstein [PR].  (As it happens
I used such coincidences in my own work a few years ago [E].)
They find all ways that three diagonals of a regular polygon can meet 
at a point: there are several infinite families (comprising algebraically "trivial" 
solutions that are not always geometrically obvious, plus the four "nontrivial"
families of Table 3 on page 12), and 65 sporadic solutions (Table 4 on page 13).
If two stars have the same inner and outer radii then we can rotate them
so they share an inner vertex; then the outer vertices are contained
among the vertices of a regular polygon, and the shared inner vertex
is on at least four diagonals $-$ indeed at least five if we include
the line of symmetry (and double the order of the regular polygon
if necessary).  Four infinite families (all symmetrical) of such
quintuple intersections are listed in Table 6 (page 16), and a
finite computation limits further sporadic solutions to denominators
18, 24, and 30 (pages 15-16).  If you've already computed far enough
to find any sporadic solutions then the infinite families must account
for everything else.

**References**

[B] Gerrit Bol: Beantwoording van prijsvraag no. 17, 
*Nieuw Archief voor Wiskunde* **18** (1936), 14-66.

[PR] Bjorn Poonen and Michael Rubinstein:
The Number of Intersection Points Made by the Diagonals of a Regular Polygon,
*SIAM J. Discrete Math* **11** (1998), 135-156
(http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/ngon.pdf).

[E] Noam D. Elkies: 
On some points-and-lines problems and configurations, 
*Periodica Mathematica Hungarica* **53** #1-2 (2006), 133-148
([arXiv:MG/0612749](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.MG/0612749)).

Comment: Splendid, thank you. Posted just too late for me to approve it, but the machine awarded you the bounty anyway. 